# R: interpolate a value from dataframe based on two inputs

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  Teff logg M_div_H       U       B      V      R      I     J     H     K     L Lprime     M
1 2000  4.0    -0.1 -13.443 -11.390 -7.895 -4.464 -1.831 1.666 3.511 2.701 4.345  4.765 5.680
2 2000  4.5    -0.1 -13.402 -11.416 -7.896 -4.454 -1.794 1.664 3.503 2.728 4.352  4.772 5.687
3 2000  5.0    -0.1 -13.358 -11.428 -7.888 -4.431 -1.738 1.664 3.488 2.753 4.361  4.779 5.685
4 2000  5.5    -0.1 -13.220 -11.079 -7.377 -4.136 -1.483 1.656 3.418 2.759 4.355  4.753 5.638
5 2200  3.5    -0.1 -11.866  -9.557 -6.378 -3.612 -1.185 1.892 3.294 2.608 3.929  4.289 4.842
6 2200  4.5    -0.1 -11.845  -9.643 -6.348 -3.589 -1.132 1.874 3.310 2.648 3.947  4.305 4.939
...
```

Let's say I have two values:

```
input_Teff = 4.8529282904170595E+003
input_log_g = 1.9241934741026787E+000
```

Notice how every `V` value has a unique `Teff`, `logg` combination. From the input values, I would like to interpolate a value for `V`. Is there a way to do this in R?

**Edit 1**: Here is the link to the full data frame: https://www.dropbox.com/s/prbceabxmd25etx/lcb98cor.dat?dl=0

Comment: It's not helpful to paste the dataframe here, especially when the columns don't line up. To give a good reproducible example, provide some of your data via `dput(head())`.

Comment: @AndyBrown Thanks for the tip. Please see the change now.

Comment: Seems like what you have is a set of points plotted in two dimension, `Teff` and `logg`. You need to calculate the "nearest" point in that space for each row of the data frame for every input value. Unfortunately, Teff and logg do not appear to exist in the same scale, so you will most likely need to first scale the values before calculating a distance. You have not provided enough the data frame to be able to answer.

Comment: @IanCampbell See edit 1.

Comment: @IanCampbell Also, after I calculate the distance, what would I do with that info to get `V`? It still is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Ian Campbell's observation that you can consider your data as points on a two-dimensional plane, you can use spatial interpolation methods. The simplest approach is inverse-distance weighting, which you can implement like this

```
library(data.table) 
d <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/prbceabxmd25etx/lcb98cor.dat?dl=1")
setnames(d,"#Teff","Teff")
```

First rescale the data as appropriate (not shown here, see Ian's answer)

```
library(gstat)
# fit model
idw <- gstat(id="V", formula = V~1, locations = ~Teff+logg, data=d, nmax=7, set=list(idp = .5))

# new "points" to predict to 
newd <- data.frame(Teff=c(4100, 4852.928), logg=c(1.5, 1.9241934741026787))

p <- predict(idw, newd)
#[inverse distance weighted interpolation]
p$V.pred
#[1] -0.9818571 -0.3602857
```

For higher dimensions you could use `fields::Tps` (I think you can force that to be an *exact* method, that is, exactly honor the observations, by making each observation a node)

Comment: Did you mean to say "not shown here" for the rescaling? Also, why do you use `4100` and `1.5` for `newd`?

Comment: Yes, should be "not". 4100 and 1.5 are just example numbers.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by example numbers here. If I put other numbers instead of 4100 and 1.5, will that affect the interpolated `V` value too much?

Comment: Also, what is `d` in data=d?

Comment: These are just examples of possible values for `Teff ` and `logg` you might want to predict to.  They do not affect each other. I fixed `d`.

Comment: Since `p$V.pred` gives two values, would I use the second value?

Comment: The first value is for the first row in the data.frame, the second value for the second row and so on.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to suppress the message. However, if you in data frame, I have columns for `lambdas <- c('U','B','V','R','I','J','H','K','L','Lprime','M')`. What changes would I make to you code to calculate the value not just for `V`, but for ALL elements in `lambdas`?

Comment: Any insights about my last comment?

Answer (score 2):

We can imagine that `Teff` and `logg` exist in a 2-dimensional plane. We can see that your input point exists in that same space:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data,aes(x = Teff, y = logg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Teff = 4.8529282904170595e3, logg = 1.9241934741026787),
             color = "orange")
```

[image]

However, we can see the scale of Teff and logg are not the same. Simply taking `log(Teff)` gets us pretty close, but not quite. So we can rescale between 0 and 1 instead. We can create a custom rescale function. It will become clear why we can't use `scales::rescale` in a moment.

```
rescale = function(x,y){(x - min(y))/(max(y)-min(y))}
```

We can now rescale the data:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Teff.scale = rescale(Teff,Teff),
         logg.scale = rescale(logg,logg)) -> data
```

From here, we might use `raster::pointDistance` to calculate the distance from the input point to all of the scaled values:

```
raster::pointDistance(cbind(rescale(input_Teff,data$Teff),rescale(input_log_g,data$logg)),
                      data[,c("Teff.scale","logg.scale")],
                      lonlat = FALSE)
```

We can use `which.min` to find the row with the minimum distance:

```
data[which.min(raster::pointDistance(cbind(rescale(input_Teff,data$Teff),rescale(input_log_g,data$logg)),
                                     data[,c("Teff.scale","logg.scale")],
                                     lonlat = FALSE)),]
   Teff logg M_div_H      U      B      V     R     I     J     H     K     L Lprime     M Teff.scale logg.scale
1: 4750    2    -0.1 -2.447 -1.438 -0.355 0.159 0.589 1.384 1.976 1.881 2.079  2.083 2.489 0.05729167  0.4631902
```

Here we can visualize the result:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = Teff.scale, y = logg.scale)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = data[which.min(raster::pointDistance(cbind(rescale(input_Teff,data$Teff),rescale(input_log_g,data$logg)),data[,c("Teff.scale","logg.scale")], FALSE)),],
             color = "blue") +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Teff.scale = rescale(input_Teff,data$Teff),logg.scale = rescale(input_log_g,data$logg)),
             color = "orange")
```

[image]

And access the appropriate value for `V`:

```
data[which.min(raster::pointDistance(cbind(rescale(input_Teff,data$Teff),rescale(input_log_g,data$logg)),data[,c("Teff.scale","logg.scale")], FALSE)),"V"]
        V
1: -0.355
```

Data:

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/prbceabxmd25etx/lcb98cor.dat?dl=1")
setnames(data,"#Teff","Teff")
input_Teff = 4.8529282904170595E+003
input_log_g = 1.9241934741026787E+000
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I appreciate that you included plots to explain the interpolation. :)